# want to check flag which is set in other table

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
 select ky as productcode
from invoice
cross join lateral jsonb_object_keys(contents) as t(ky)
where orgcode=48 and invoice.inoutflag=15
group by ky
order by count(*) desc
limit(5);
```

Right now I get top five product code but there is one flag in other table name as "product" and I want top five product code if flag=7.

this is product table

```
 productcode | gscode | gsflag | productdesc |  
----------------+----------+----------+------- ----------+

     50      | 444   |   7  |   car     |
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.ky as productcode
from invoice i cross join lateral
     jsonb_object_keys(i.contents) as t(ky) join
     product p
     on p.productcode = t.ky
where i.orgcode = 48 and i.inoutflag = 15 and
      p.gsflag = 7
group by t.ky
order by count(*) desc
limit 5;
```

Comment: got this ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = text
LINE 1: ...ontents) as t(ky) join product p on p.productcode = t.ky whe...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: @rupali . . . Then cast the values to the appropriate types.  Your question certainly does not show what the types of the various columns are, but you should know that.